# How to resolve the following error message?

Tags: api, token, nest-api

Invoke-WebRequest : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'L'.
At line:1 char:6

- curl -L -X POST 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token?
- ```
   ~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Comment: Did you try any other GET or POST requests? Specifically on URLs that don't need verification? Do they throw the same error? And can you please edit your question, so that the styling is more clear? Please include comments in between the errors, so that it becomes more clear.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, `curl` is an alias for PowerShell's `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet, which can cause issues when running curl commands in a PowerShell prompt because the arguments for curl and the arguments for `Invoke-WebRequest` are not the same. It's an unfortunate historical decision that is somewhat tricky to remove because there may be many scripts relying on the behaviour.

To resolve, you can either

- [download curl for Windows](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html), add to the `PATH` variable, remove the PowerShell alias (`rm alias:curl`, you might want to [add to your PowerShell profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/ise/how-to-use-profiles-in-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-7.1#to-edit-a-profile)), and run the command again with `curl`

or

- Use `Invoke-WebRequest` with the equivalent arguments, which would be

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token -Method Post
```

The `-L` command of `curl` is not needed for `Invoke-WebRequest` as it follows redirects by default (up to 5), but this can be increased with `-MaximumRedirection` argument.